# Вернуть ответ в аякс

Tags: php, ajax, route

Всем привет помогите доорганизовать чтобы получилось возвращать результат в аякс функции.. У меня никаких роутов, и.т.д нету кроме аутолоадера.

Я понимаю чтобы вернуть результат аяксу нужно обращатся к функции которая вернёт результат через return , но как это сделать? на данный момент у меня вот что есть:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


if (isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city'])) {


        $providers = [
            'app\Provider\YahooProvider',
            'app\Provider\OpenWeatherMapProvider',
        ];

        $apiKeys = [
            'YahooProvider' =>   '',
            'OpenWeatherMap' => '',
        ];

        $temperature = new app\Provider\DelegatingProvider($providers, $apiKeys);
        $location = new app\Location\Location($_POST['city']);

        $weather = $temperature->fetch($location);

        return json_encode($weather);

}
```

в принципе это моя точка и есть от куда мне бы и хотелось получить результат..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather apps</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Enter city for get temperature:</h1>
    <input type="text" id="city" value=""> <button>Get weather</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $('button').click(function(){

            var city = document.getElementById('city');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/app.php',
                data: { city : city.value },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })    
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Всегда работал на готовых решениях фраймворках, когда всё организовано легко работается даже не задумываешся )) понимаю что много пробелов у меня решил попрактиковатся с нуля...

---

[image: это var_dump обьекта weather первый просто обьект второй json_decode]

на картинке возвращаю

```
var_dump($weather);
var_dump(json_encode($weather)); // почему-то {}
```

почему-то json_encode в response {} пусто если без него то нормальный обьект, а через echo do not object convert to string

Comment: [![это var_dump обьекта weather первый просто обьект второй json_decode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvqQs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvqQs.png) на картинке возвращаю var_dump($weather); var_dump(json_encode($weather)); // почему-то {} почему-то json_encode в response {} пусто если без него то нормальный обьект, а через echo do not object convert to string

Comment: Не decode, а encode

Comment: извиняюсь не правильно написал, encode использовал

Comment: echo json_encode(get_object_vars($weather))

Comment: не могу понять почему он не может конвертировать в данном случаи в reponse [ ] вместо {}

Comment: вот если так всё ок integer возвращает echo json_encode($weather->getTemperature()); что в обьекте ему этом может не нравится?

Comment: Да, прошу прощенья, все верно... get_object_vars не поможет, у Вас приватные свойства, и потому Вам нужно сформировать массив на основе методов объекта. И потом сделать json_encode($array)

Comment: Какой `return`? AJAX требует, чтобы сервер возвратил данные, закодированные в JSON. Вернул так же, как и обычную HTML-страницу, через `echo`. Всё. Дальше клиент получит этот JSON и будет работать с ним сам.

Comment: @Art ur, судя по всему Вы используете какой-то фреймворк. У него есть свой API, который важно учитывать для того чтобы Вам помочь. Напишите пожалуйста что Вы используете и добавьте это в вопрос в виде текста и метки(если таковая есть).

Comment: @Art ur, что загружает автолоадер?

Comment: я решил проблему, фраймворк не использую, аутолоадер загружает мной написанные классы которые в папке /app/, проблема была то что я пытался вернуть класс в json_encode и ничего не получал, это было всё потому что у класса переменные приватные

Comment: Разберитесь с терминологией

Comment: Если ответ помог вам решить вашу задачу, вы можете отметить его как верный (зеленая галочка под стрелками).

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo json_encode($weather);
```

Всё просто!

Проблема у вас в том что вы делаете 2 вывода

```
 var_dump($weather);
var_dump(json_encode($weather));
```

Тем самым ломая структуру json-а.

Answer (score 0):

PHP код - это и есть app.php ?
Сделайте не return а echo )

Comment: ну да app.php в нём вызываются другие файлы там обработка и возвращается всё в него и он должен вернуть аяксу..